# EF Core sets the Foreign Key constraint as 'ON DELETE RESTRICT' even though the FK is nullable

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using EF Core with PostgreSQL using Npgsql and I have set the Foreign Key of the dependent entity (Chapter, see below) as nullable int. I was expecting when I delete the principle entity (in this case Book) CASCADE NULL will happen. Instead in the migration the behavior is ON DELETE RESTRICT. So when I try to delete the Book entity it throws

> update or delete on table "Books" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Chapters_Books_BookId" on table "Chapters"

Shouldn't it be ON DELETE SET NULL by default? How to make it SET NULL?

#### Include your code

Book entity:

```
[Index(nameof(ISBN))]
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string ISBN { get; set; }

    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
```

Chapter entity:

```
public class Chapter
{
    public int ChapterId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? BookId { get; set; }    //  <--- nullable
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Generated Migration for Chapter Entity:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Chapters",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ChapterId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
        Title = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
        BookId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true),
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Chapters", x => x.ChapterId);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Chapters_Books_BookId",
            column: x => x.BookId,
            principalTable: "Books",
            principalColumn: "BookId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);         // <---  Why??????
    });
```

As you can see above the `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict)` has restrict in it. Why not `SetNull` by default?

#### Include stack traces

```
Message: 
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
    ---- Npgsql.PostgresException : 23503: update or delete on table "Books" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Chapters_Books_BookId" on table "Chapters"
  Stack Trace: 
    ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
    BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
    RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
    StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
    StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
    StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    DbContext.SaveChanges()
    BookServicesTests.RegisterNewBook_CanSuccessfullySaveToDatabase() line 63
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
    NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
    NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
    NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
    RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
    ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
```

#### Include provider and version information

- EF Core version: 5.0.4
- Database provider: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
- Target framework:  .NET 5.0
- Operating system: Windows 10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019 16.10)

Comment: Why? Because [that's the default behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#cascade-delete). See also [Configuring cascading behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#configuring-cascading-behaviors)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, because the database column in the Book model that the Chapter model is a foreign key to is not a nullable type itself.

I think your schema itself is rather incorrect. You don't need to make the BookId field a nullable type since all chapters in a literal book must belong to a Book in code.

Try correcting that schema error.

Thanks